# Test Result Report in Jenkins Pipeline using Groovy | Pipeline Execution | Report Types

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration

I am setting up test result reporting in Jenkins for test projects written in various test frameworks (NUnit, MSTest, etc) and would like to improve my understanding with regards to report types and the difference between stages and post in the pipeline execution.

Answer (score 0):

**Pipeline Execution**

Stages are executed in the order in which they appear and if there are any stages after and the one before fails the following stages will not get executed.

Where post gets executed regardless of whether or not the stages completed successfully or not, after the stages execution.

**Report Types**

Provided I have a stage (produces test result):

```
stage('MSTest') {
  steps {
    bat(script: 'dotnet test "..\\TestsProject.csproj" --logger "trx;LogFileName=TestResult.xml"')
  }
}
```

And a post that runs always (consume test result to produce test result report):

```
post {
always {
  xunit testTimeMargin: '5000', thresholdMode: 1, thresholds: [], tools: [ReportType(deleteOutputFiles: true, failIfNotNew: false, pattern: '..\\TestResult.xml', skipNoTestFiles: false, stopProcessingIfError: false)]
}
```

}

Project variations:

Provided my test project is written in NUnit the 'ReportType' method in 'tools:' will need to be replaced with NUnit3 for the post to execute successfully.

Provided my test project is written in MSTest the 'ReportType' method in 'tools:' will need to be replaced with MSTest for the post to execute successfully.